# multiple function from view to controller

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

i have two function in my controller:-

```
public function get_subject()   { // codes......... }
```

and

```
public function subject_add(){ //codes................}
```

i want to display them on view using javascript at the same time, here are my java-script code:-

```
$(document).on("click","#subject",function(e){
e.preventDefault();


    $.post('<?php echo  site_url("controller_subject/subject_add"); ?>',function(responce){
    $("#contents").html(responce);
}); });
```

Comment: What you do **in the method** is rather relevant to the correct functioning of this **bare skeleton code**

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe html tag to view that both function's on view.
Here is a example:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo  site_url("controller_subject/subject_add"); ?>"></iframe>
```

This will be help you to load both functions on a same view

Hope this will help you.
Happy Coding :)